# Stylesheet is not loaded because of MIME-type

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack

After building the application build via npm run build and uploading the static folder to the server I get the above error mentioned. There is also another error:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'`

I did not change anything in the application code. I only replaced the static folder on the server, creating a new build beforehand.

I have read in several threads on this forum that it is the wrong path to the css file in index.html. But in my index.html file this path is not there. I also took interest in configuring the webpack.config.js file but everything is fine there.

I'm out of ideas and fixing these bugs takes time. When nothing works I run out of ideas on how to proceed.

Screenshot with errors below. Link to website [here](https://delightart.co).
I'll just add that after the previous build and uploading it to the server, the site worked without any problems.

As a last resort, I removed the package-lock.json file all node_module and restarted with `npm install` then `npm start`. It helped, but for a short time. After uploading the static folder to the server, a white page background and no content appears on the main page. Of course with the same errors in the debugger as before.

Comment: It seems that untranspiled JSX code ended up in your build somehow. Are you using Create React App or did you configure Webpack by yourself?

Comment: I use create react app

Comment: And why are you uploading only your `static` directory? You should upload the full content of the `build` directory (also check for cache issues in your web server or client browser when switching builds).

Comment: The path for `css` files in your `index.html` will be eventually added by Webpack automatically (check your `index.html` file in the `build` directory). In some cases, no `css` files are added because styles are embedded in `js` modules. However, this does not seem to be the issue. Your error is a JavaScript exception and it seems to be caused by an untranspiled JSX statement (an unexpected `<`).

Comment: @Ernesto Stifano Thank you so much. I have created new build and added all files to hosting. It helped.